# Transforming a generic interface type in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to create a function that accepts a generic type that is an object with keys and values and returns a type with the same interface but modifies the values of that object. It's a little hard to explain in plain English, so here's an example:

Here's a contrived class that has a generic type and wraps a value

```
class Wrap<A> {
    constructor(public value: A) {}
}
```

I want to create two functions `wrap` and `unwrap` that take an object and make sure all the values are wrapped or unwrapped. Here are the functions in vanilla js:

```
function wrap(obj) {
    const result = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (obj[key] instanceof Wrap) {
            result[key] = obj[key]
        } else {
            result[key] = new Wrap(obj[key])
        }
    })
    return result
}

function unwrap(obj) {
    const result = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (obj[key] instanceof Wrap) {
            result[key] = obj[key].value
        } else {
            result[key] = obj[key]
        }
    })
    return result
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create type signatures for these functions while maintaining as much type safety as possible. For example, if the input type is an interface, I want to output an interface as well:

```
interface Ex1Input {
    a: number
    b: string
}

interface Ex1Output {
    a: Wrap<number>
    b: Wrap<string>
}

interface Ex2Input {
    a: number
    b: Wrap<string>
}

interface Ex2Output {
    a: Wrap<number>
    b: Wrap<string>
}
```

I do not want to input and output an arbitrary `{[key: string]: Wrap<any>}` because I want to maintain the type safety of the interface.

Same with the `unwrap` function:

```
interface Ex3Input {
    a: Wrap<number>
    b: Wrap<string>
}

interface Ex3Output {
    a: number
    b: string
}

interface Ex4Input {
    a: number
    b: Wrap<string>
}

interface Ex4Output {
    a: number
    b: string
}
```

I've tried a few different things... This is maybe the closest I've gotten, but I feel like its still pretty far from working as I would like.

```
interface WrapInput {
    [key: string]: any
}

interface WrapOutput extends WrapInput {
    [key: string]: Wrap<WrapInput[keyof WrapInput]>
}

function wrap<T extends WrapInput>(obj: T): WrapOutput {
    const result: WrapOutput = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (obj[key] instanceof Wrap) {
            result[key] = obj[key]
        } else {
            result[key] = new Wrap(obj[key])
        }
    })
    return result
}
```

Any ideas? Is this possible? Just to reiterate -- I'm interested in a solution that is as typesafe as possible. So if I use `wrap` with `Ex1Input`, the autocomplete in my editor should show me that there are only two properties on the output and their specific types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (`MaybeWrapped` and `Wrapped` in the following example).

```
class Wrap<Value> {
  constructor(public value: Value) {}
}

type MaybeWrapped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] | Wrap<T[K]>;
};

type Wrapped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Wrap<T[K]>;
};

function wrap<T>(arg: MaybeWrapped<T>): Wrapped<T> {
  // your implementation here
}

function unwrap<T>(arg: MaybeWrapped<T>): T {
  // your implementation here
}

declare const input: {
  a: Wrap<string>
  b: Date
};

const wrapped = wrap(input);
wrapped.a.value.length; // wrapped.a is infered as Wrap<string>
wrapped.b.value.getTime(); // wrapped.b is infered as Wrap<Date>

const unwrapped = unwrap(input);
unwrapped.a.length; // unwrapped.a is infered as string
unwrapped.b.getTime(); // unwrapped.b is infered as Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following..

```
function wrap<T>(obj: T): T {
    const result: any = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if ((obj as any)[key] instanceof Wrap) {
            result[key] = (obj as any)[key]
        } else {
            result[key] = new Wrap((obj as any)[key])
        }
    })
    return result
}


const data = { someData: 1 }
var test = wrap(data)
test.someData //  the autocomplete in my editor shows someData with intellisense
```

Comment: Thanks for answering in SO. Please describe your answer to explain what you are doing. Think of sitting next to the person who asked the question and trying to explain how to solve the problem rather than handing out the answer.